# Как выделить вставную конструкцию в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, вставная-конструкция

**Я не знаю, когда ты прочитаешь это сообщение, – *через несколько минут или с утра*, – но знай...** Я выделил часть предложения курсивом. Какими знаками лучше выделить эту часть предложения? Возможен ли вариант, который указал я?

Answer (score 2):

Ваш вариант никак не возможен.

*Я не знаю, когда ты прочитаешь это сообщение – через несколько минут или с утра, но знай...*

Придаточное в двух запятых со своим "родным" тире. "Закрывать" его нет необходимости.

Как-то других вариантов я и не наблюдаю...

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант со вставкой:**

**Я не знаю, когда ты прочитаешь это сообщение – через несколько минут или с утра, – но знай...**

Два тире, перенесенная запятая. Если оставить одно тире, то интонация будет встроенной, а не вставочной, а это значит, что не будет  паузы вообще. Но эту вставку желательно выделить паузами.

Розенталь (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123):

> **Когда он начинает сомневаться в себе — а это с ним изредка происходит, — он пытается стать рационалистом** — вставное предложение примыкает к предшествующей придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, и запятая ставится после всей конструкции;